# Pascal GUI Centering

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

how can i center my output pascal triangle in a JTextarea? 
my pascal triangle print in left i want print it in center...
this is my code

```
public static int ComputePascal(int rows) {
    for(int i =0;i<rows;i++) {
       int number = 1;           
       String a = String.format("%"+(rows-i)*2+"s","");
        area.append(a);
        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++) {
       String b = String.format("%4d",number);
        area.append(b);
            number = number * (i - j) / (j + 1);
       }
   String c = String.format("%n");
    area.append(c);
    }
    return rows;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A JTextArea doesn't support the centering of text.

Instead you can use a `JTextPane` and set the attributes for each paragraph to be centered:

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), center, false);
```

A JTextPane doesn't support an `append(...)` method so you will need to insert the text directly into the document:

```
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "your text here...", null );
```